# Hosting and stopping a minecraft server through subprocess on python

Tags: python, minecraft

I've been trying to write a python script to control the starting and stopping of a minecraft server. I've got it to accept commands through input() but i also wanted the logs of the server to be printed on the console(or be processed someway), since that the process never ends, readline hangs everytime the server finished outputing text,no further input can be performed. Is there a way to let stdin and stdout to work simultaneously,or is there a way to time out readline so i can continue?

The code i've got so far:

```
import subprocess
from subprocess import PIPE
import os

minecraft_dir = "D:\Minecraft Server"
executable = 'java -Xms4G -Xmx4G -jar "D:\Minecraft Server\paper-27.jar" java'
process = None

def server_command(cmd):
    if(process is not None):
        cmd = cmd + '\n'
        cmd = cmd.encode("utf-8")
        print(cmd)
        process.stdin.write(cmd)
        process.stdin.flush()
    else:
        print("Server is not running.")

def server_stop():
    if process is None:
        print("Server is not running.")
    else:
        process.stdin.write("stop\n".encode("utf-8"))
        process.stdin.flush()

while True:
    command=input()
    command=command.lower()
    if(command == "start"):
        if process is None:
            os.chdir(minecraft_dir)
            process = subprocess.Popen(executable,stdin=PIPE,stdout=PIPE)
            print("Server started.")
        else:
            print("Server Already Running.")
    elif(command == "stop"):
        server_stop()
        process=None
    else:
        server_command(command)
```

I've mentioned processing the server log someway or the other because i don't really need it on the console,since i can always read from a file that it generated. But this particular server i'm running needs the stdout=PIPE argument or it throws out

```
java.io.IOException: ReadConsoleInputW failed
        at org.fusesource.jansi.internal.Kernel32.readConsoleInputHelper(Kernel32.java:816)
        at org.fusesource.jansi.internal.WindowsSupport.readConsoleInput(WindowsSupport.java:99)
        at org.jline.terminal.impl.jansi.win.JansiWinSysTerminal.processConsoleInput(JansiWinSysTerminal.java:112)
        at org.jline.terminal.impl.AbstractWindowsTerminal.pump(AbstractWindowsTerminal.java:458)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

and i think it breaks the PIPE? Because no further input is directed to the process(process.stdin.write not working), yet the process is still running.

Any help on either one of the issue would be greatly appreciated.